# How can I get elements in Tkinter windows to fill the frame?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to Python GUI development with Tkinter.
I am trying to make the app window a certain size and I want the webcam view in the window to fill the size of the main window.

When I set the window size, the webcam does not fill the entire window.

How can I make the elements fill the entire window when I customize the size of the window?

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2

class MainWindow():
    def __init__(self, window, cap):
        self.window = window
        self.cap = cap
        self.width = self.cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
        self.height = self.cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
        self.interval = 20 # Interval in ms to get the latest frame

        # Create canvas for image
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.window, width=self.width, height=self.height)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        # Update image on canvas
        self.update_image()

    def update_image(self):
        # Get the latest frame and convert image format
        self.image = cv2.cvtColor(self.cap.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # to RGB
        self.image = Image.fromarray(self.image) # to PIL format
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image) # to ImageTk format

        # Update image
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=tk.NW, image=self.image)

        # Repeat every 'interval' ms
        self.window.after(self.interval, self.update_image)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('600x800')
    # root.resizable(width=0, height=0)
    MainWindow(root, cv2.VideoCapture(0))

    root.mainloop()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is resize the image to fit the canvas size. You can either use `cv2.resize()` or `Image.resize()` to resize the image.

To get the current canvas size use `canvas.winfo_height()` and `canvas.wifo_width()`. Besides that, you should also consider updating the existing image using `canvas.itemconfig(tag_id)`, instead of creating a new one each time.

sample code (I'll be using a label instead of canvas to display the image):

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2

class MainWindow():
    def __init__(self, window, cap):
        self.window = window
        self.cap = cap

        self.interval = 20 # Interval in ms to get the latest frame
        # Create canvas for image
        self.vid_lbl = tk.Label(self.window)
        self.vid_lbl.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        # Update image on canvas
        self.update_image()

    def update_image(self):
        # Get the latest frame and convert image format

        width, height = self.vid_lbl.winfo_width(), self.vid_lbl.winfo_height()

        self.image = cv2.cvtColor(self.cap.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # to RGB
        self.image = cv2.resize(self.image, (width, height), cv2.INTER_AREA)
        self.image = Image.fromarray(self.image) # to PIL format
        #self.image = self.image.resize((width, height))

        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image) # to ImageTk format
        self.vid_lbl.config(image=self.image)

        # Repeat every 'interval' ms
        self.window.after(self.interval, self.update_image)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('600x800')
    # root.resizable(width=0, height=0)
    MainWindow(root, cv2.VideoCapture(0))

    root.mainloop()
```